# Android - Cannot set the LIstView background color use ListFragement

Tags: android, listview

I create a colors.xml and have a list_fragment.xml as the following and the listView background color is not change to blue?

colors.xml

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
               <resources>
                  <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
                  <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
                  <color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
                  <color name="orange">#ff5500</color>
                  <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
                  <color name="black">#000000</color>
                  <color name="gray">#999999</color>
                  <color name="blue">#0066cc</color>
            </resources>
```

list_fragment.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context=".HomePageListFragment">


       <ListView
         android:id="@android:id/list"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="@color/blue"
       </ListView>

     </LinearLayout>enter code here
```

Thanks,
Jo

Comment: Are you filling the list with items that aren't colored blue?

Comment: Hi Bruce, what do you mean by filling the list with items? How to set this attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is not well formed:

```
  <ListView
     android:id="@android:id/list" <=== change it to android:id="@+id/list"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@color/blue"  <=== missing ">" to close the tag
   </ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried to close the tag it's still not working. 
<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:entries="@array/food_spaces"/>

Comment: This weird this works perfectly fine:  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/blue" />

</LinearLayout>

Comment: I changed the id tag to android:id="@+id/list" as well, the color is still not changed. I am using Android Studio 4.0